# Hibernate search aggregation : countByDocumentType (with elaticsearch backend)

Tags: hibernate, elasticsearch, hibernate-search

I'am coding a simple query which targeting multiple index :

```
//targetIndexes is a list of indexes
searchSession.search(targetIndexes).extension(ElasticsearchExtension.get())
```

Now I simply want a "countByDocumentType". It means that I want the number of result grouped by the index type. For this I have got two fields already present in my stored index, but I can't query them with hibernate search, damn it !
Actually, elastic search adds its native field named "_index" to allow filtering by index. Hibernate search add also its native field named "_entity_type". But I neither can query on "_index" nor "_entity_type" with hibernate search using aggregation like this :

```
AggregationKey<Map<String, Long>> countsByEntityKey = AggregationKey.of( "countsByEntity" );
...where(...).aggregation(countsByEntityKey, f -> f.terms()
                .field( "_entity_type", String.class ));
```

So do I really need to pollute all my classes by adding a custom third field into each hibernate mapped entities in order to be able to query on a specific index ?

```
@Indexed
public class MyIndexedEntity {
    ...
    @GenericField
    public String getEntityName() {
         return this.getClass.getName();
    }
}
```

Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Starting with Hibernate Search 6.2.0.Alpha2, you can refer to *some* fields that are not part of the Hibernate Search mapping in the Hibernate Search DSL: `_id`, `_index`, `_entity_type`.

So your code should just work.

---

Previous answer:

Before Hibernate Search 6.2.0.Alpha2, you can't refer to fields that are not part of the Hibernate Search mapping in the Hibernate Search DSL.

I'd suggest using a [native aggregation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-dsl-aggregation-extensions-elasticsearch-from-json):

```java
AggregationKey<JsonObject> countsByEntityTypeKey = AggregationKey.of( "countsByEntityType" );
SearchResult<Book> result = searchSession.search( Arrays.asList( Book.class, Author.class ) )
        .extension( ElasticsearchExtension.get() )
        .where( f -> f.matchAll() )
        .aggregation( countsByEntityTypeKey, f -> f.fromJson( "{\"terms\":{\"field\": \"_entity_type\"}}" ) )
        .fetch( 20 );

JsonObject countsByEntityTypeAsJson = result.aggregation( countsByEntityTypeKey );
Map<String, Long> countsByEntityType = new HashMap<>();
for ( JsonElement bucket: countsByEntityTypeAsJson.get("buckets").getAsJsonArray() ) {
    JsonObject bucketObject = bucket.getAsJsonObject();
    countsByEntityType.put( bucketObject.get( "key" ).getAsString(),
            bucketObject.get( "doc_count" ).getAsLong() );
}
```

You can still use the (less verbose) Hibernate Search APIs for everything else, in the same query.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. I was just going to post the same answer, I found it like you did. Nice, it is good to be able to turn on "specific" mode with fromJson's elastic method. The low level api allows it. Thanks !